# Using a variable as a directory name in perl

Tags: perl, variables, directory

I am using a user input variable as my initial directory name, but when trying to expand the directory and create sub-folders, utilizing that variable causes issue in the path.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "What would you like to name your directory?\n"; 
chomp( my $directory = <STDIN> );

mkdir $directory, 0755;
mkdir $directory/data, 0755; ##<----<<Error begins here##
mkdir $directory/data/image, 0755;
mkdir $directory/data/cache, 0755;
```

Comment: `use diagnostics;` and try again.

Comment: That helped out immensely, awesome.

Comment: Kudos for `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.  Tiz nice to see a new user having already learned that most important lesson.

Answer (score 4):

Unquoted `/` in Perl means division or regular expression match. Quote it if it's part of a string:

```
mkdir "$directory/data", 0755;
```

Answer (score 3):

Or try

```
use File::Path qw/ make_path /;

make_path( "${directory}/data/image", "${directory}/data/cache" );
```

it will create the intermediate directories for you.

You may also want to look at the [`Path::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) or [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) modules, which have a nicer OO-interface for file operations.